# Reading in a file, how does variable assignment and scope work?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to understand how a file is read into a javascript and I came across the code [here](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/bdf28027e0ce70bd132edc64f1dd7ea4) that is really throwing me for a loop. Heres what I think is happening:

1. the csv is read in and assigned to the variable "data" which only exists inside the {}.
2. then for each line of data assign it to variable "d" and do something to it.

My questions:

How can you then reference "d" outside of the foreach loop? Isn't it local to the loop? what variable type is "d.sales", some kind of reference to object d? And finally, where the heck did "d.salesperson" get created?

Snippet:

```
d3.csv("sales.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  // format the data
  data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.sales = +d.sales;
  });
 // Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.salesperson; }));
....
```

Comment: You could try logging out the object to console, and see its structure. Then it might be a bit clearer. Generally, a javascript object is just lots of nested objects and arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you look in the code from that page. The csv file contains `salesperson` and `sales`.
 1 - You are correct in saying that the files is read in and the contents are assigned to `data`
 2 - Kind of. You should look up what `forEach` does and its format. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach
But yes `d` in this case is the reference to each datum in your data. Given the csv, each datum has a `sales` property and a `salesperson` property.

> How can you then reference "d" outside of the foreach loop? Isn't it local to the loop? what variable type is "d.sales", some kind of reference to object d? And finally, where the heck did "d.salesperson" get created?

`d` is just a reference. You can name it anything you want. Its just a reference to each of the datum within the data. They are not the same `d`, though they reference the same datum.

```
data.forEach(function(value, index, array){});
```

The `forEach` function is a loop that has access to the following items within the data its looping over, `value` - which is each datum within the array, `index` which is the index of that value, and `array` which is the array itself. The `d` in your case is the name given to the `value` part of the function.

When d3 reads in the file it creates an array of objects each with properties based on the headers in the csv file. in this case its like this:

```
[{
    "salesperson": "Bob",
    "sales": 33 
}, {
    ...
}]
```

You should really do some basic javascript before trying to pull apart a d3 graph. Also if youre not trying to do a graph and only trying to read a csv file, d3 is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

A good thing to remember with JavaScript is that there is no *block-level* scope. That would tip you off that d would not be "local to the loop".  But that really doesn't help you here. "d" is just an arbitrarily-named reference that is scoped to each of the *functions* in which it appears in your code snippet.

1. Yes, and data is an array.
2. .forEach and .map are array functions that take as a parameter a function that is applied to each element (d) of the array (data).

the d3.csv() function reads the file and creates each element of the data array, with each element containing sales and salesperson properties.